# github: determining when commits were done if all pushed together

Tags: git, github

If I make several commits hours apart from each other and push them all at the same time, is there a way to distinguish on Github the that the commits were made hours apart from each other or does it just base it off when they were pushed?

Comment: Commits themselves have timestamps. Look at the `$git log`

Comment: .. and the time you push something is actually not relevant _at all_... at least to git. github might keep a log of when that happens, but it's certainly not part of the information that git keeps about revisions.

Comment: @MattClark I know git has them but I couldn't find them in github so I am questioning if that's exposed anywhere in github

Comment: They did change the UI and for a new user it's not very obvious how to get there - inthe code section of your project, on the line with the latest commit, click where it says "n# commits" or by url: `github.com/<owner>/<repo>/commits`